# Web3j and Uniswap Router V2, converting wei to uint256

Tags: java, ethereum, smartcontracts, web3-java

the issue I'm having is that I'm trying to send a value in wei to `swapExactETHForTokens`, but it returns `Fail with error 'UniswapV2Library: INSUFFICIENT_INPUT_AMOUNT'`. If I convert 1 ETH to wei (in code) it comes out as `1000000000000000000`. When doing a swap from the Uniswap GUI it turns 1 ETH to `1059503741842561918508100943433`.
I'll put my code below, guess I'll look into the Uniswap frontend project to see how it converts the 1 ETH in the GUI to that value (guess it also adds the fees before calling the smart contract)

```
  web3j = Web3j.build(web3jService);
        UniswapV2Router02 uniSwapRouter = UniswapV2Router02.load(UNISWAP_V2_RINKEBY, 
                web3j, 
                credentials, 
                new DefaultGasProvider());
        uniSwapRouter.swapExactETHForTokens(
                Convert.toWei("1", Convert.Unit.ETHER).toBigInteger(),
                Arrays.asList(WETH_ADDRESS, DAI_ADDRESS),
                credentials.getAddress(),
                BigInteger.valueOf(DEADLINE_TIMESTAMP)).send();
```

What I will try:

- try and convert the amount to uint256, trailing zeros and all (not sure how though)
- look at how the frontend is doing it, not sure if I should call `swapExactETHForTokens` directly, without calling some other function before

So some questions would be:

- how can I turn lets say a value of 1 ETH to a BigInteger representing that uint256 number?
- should I call other functions beforehand?
- how do I set the gas? I guess through the `new DefaultGasProvider()`
- I saw that in Javascript they do something like `const MIN_TOKENS = web3.utils.toHex(0.2 * 10 ** 18)`, how can I do this in Web3 without being hackish and add trailing zeros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny how posting a question here helps with rubber ducking, isn't it?

Looked at the contract and it reads msg.value. Guess what, we're not sending that. Even though the `swapExactEthForTokens` is a payable, the wrapper isn't generating a parameter for it.

Follow this bug for more info: https://github.com/web3j/web3j/issues/1268

I was basically sending a transaction with 0 ether, ofc it returned `INSUFFICIENT_INPUT_AMOUNT`. Thought that if the Java Wrapper only gave me that first amount it would automatically take care of it but nope.

What I had to do was manually add the weiValue to `executeRemoteCallTransaction(function, weiValue)` because the wrapper doesn't do that, look at the above bug report.

Anyway, I'll leave this open in case anyone wants to chime-in with more insights.